# Calculation puzzle 011

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

Find the missing number.

```
   17   |   8   |   5   |   5
--------------------------------
   20   |   4   |   6   |   4   
--------------------------------
   18   |   3   |   7   |   3   
--------------------------------
    7   |   ?   |   8   |   2
```

Source: This question is taken from YTU YOS 2018 exam. I have mentioned those exams in my other posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 9.  First + second = third * fourth